# how to fix image dynamically in round layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am pretty much new to android..Is it possible to fix image dynamically in a rounded layout? Can we use xml code to do that if it is can you suggest me how to write the code for that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This calls used for make image bitmap in round shape.

```
public class ImageHelper {
    public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
                .getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to call the method getRoundedCornerBitmap() and where we can declare the bitmap image?

Comment: just pass image bitmap and pixels.

Comment: yeah it worked for me but I could not place the image exactly center of the layout. Can you suggest me how to do it?

Comment: change image position in layout xml file.